# Change response format of REST API

Tags: php, json, api

I'm working on my REST API responses with PHP.
Here is my backend that generates the responses:

```
  $query = $this->db->query("SELECT some_params from some_table ");
  $result = $query->result();  

  foreach($result as $row){
     $obj[] = array(
          'title' => $row['title'],
          'price' => $row['price'],
     );
  }
  print_r(json_encode($obj));
```

and with that I have the following response: an **array of json objects**

```
[
  {
    "title":"Marketing",
    "price":"0"
  },
  {
    "title":"SAP B1",
    "price":"10"
  }
]
```

> What I would like to do is return a **new object**, something like this:

```
{ 
  "apiVersion": "2.0",
  "data": {
       {
          "title":"Marketing",
          "price":"0"
       },
       {
           "title":"SAP B1",
           "price":"10"
       }
   }
}
```

Does anyone have any idea how I could implement this? thanks!

Comment: What you say you want is not valid JSON.  A valid version would be exactly what you already have, just nested one level deep in another (associative) array.

Comment: @PatrickQ Thanks for the answer! Let me see if I got it.... I can use the array of objects from the first example in the structure I proposed in the second example, is that so?

Comment: Basically, yeah.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily have a class or function to do that for you. Some thing like below should help,

```
// provided you are using php > 7 . otherwise parmas
// can become $data, $apiversion ( without typecasting )
function api_reponse(array $data, string $apiVersion)
{
   return json_encode([
       'apiVersion' => $apiVersion,
       'data'       => $data
   ])
}
```

You can then use,

```
  $query = $this->db->query("SELECT some_params from some_table ");
  $result = $query->result();  

  foreach($result as $row){
     $obj[] = array(
          'title' => $row['title'],
          'price' => $row['price'],
     );
  }

  print_r( api_response($obj, '2.0') );
```